# Linq : "New " keyword not working for multi fields selection (Dynamic Library)

Tags: linq, dynamic

I updated the DynamicLibrary code to be able to launch a query such as :

```
objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select(obj => obj.name);
```

It's working fine.
Now I'm trying to get this one working :

```
objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select(new {obj.name, obj.type});
```

Not working... Then, I looked at the "New" keyword parser in DynamicLibrary.cs. So I tried :

```
objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select("new(obj.name, obj.type)");
```

And now I'm getting something like : "')' is missing"..

(I'm still a beginner with Linq)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Something like" or "exactly"? Specifying the *exact* error message is usually useful.

Comment: Shouldn't your second snippet be `objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select(obj => new {obj.name, obj.type});` ?

Comment: @Jon : sorry I had to reboot my computer for different reasons and couldn't launch my exe anymore. Here is the complete message : ')' or ',' expected

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your

```
       objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select(new {obj.name, obj.type});
```

should be actually

```
       objects.Where(obj => obj.color == "blue").Select(obj => new {obj.name, obj.type});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yeah, you're right, I forgot the "obj =>" part. Thanks.
But I'm still getting an error in DynamicLibrary.cs : '(' expected
In method "ParseNew()". It's waiting for a '(' instead of '{'

Answer (score 0):

There is an evolution of the Dynamic Linq library that uses the c# dynamic keyword so you don't have strings [available in nuget](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/DynamicLINQ), and while it's not complete the original dynamic linq sample code library wasn't quite complete either, my be worth checking out. Here is a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/08/19/dynamic-linq-part-2-evolution.aspx) about it.